# How to create HTML form from HTML Schema (XSD)

Tags: xml, xsd, forms

I have a XML Schema (XSD) and I would like to convert it automatically in HTML form. 
Do you know any engine?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Tool recommendations are out of scope for Stack Overflow**, but be aware of the efforts of [**The Forms Working Group**](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/Forms/) at the W3C.  Note in particular the [**XForms Implementations**](http://www.w3.org/community/xformsusers/wiki/XForms_Implementations) Wiki page hosted there.